# Campden and Pectic enzyme

Tags: wine, primary-fermentation, campden, pectic-enzyme

I read a recipe specifying that pectic is to be added 12 hours after the addition of Campden. Until now I've been mixing in all my additives at the same time, and haven't had any problems.

My question is: Does Campden kill off the enzymes if added at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

According to [jackkeller.net](http://winemaking.jackkeller.net/adding.asp), the action of pectic enzymes is reduced by high levels of sulphur dioxide. The gases dissipate after the addition of the campden tablets, which is the reason for recommending to wait 12 hours before adding the enzymes. (Whether the enzymes are actually denatured by the sulphur dioxide is somewhat unclear.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you starting a brew or finishing one off?
Rule of thumb to keep handy when using any kind of enzyme in brewing; enzymes are proteins and proteins don’t mix well with bentonite or with sulfur dioxide. Always wait at least 12 hours, like your package directions dictate, between using sulfur dioxide and one of the other two products. In your particular situation, I would say that you could re-add some of the pectic enzyme, say, a half dose or so. All you’re doing is settling out pectins anyway and it should not harm the must.

Just so you’re aware, enzymatic activity can also be inhibited by high alcohol, low temperatures as well as high temperatures. Always try to avoid these situations but if you can’t, it’s generally alright to use a little more enzyme than you normally would to account for it